# Foundry: forge create with an address[] as --constructor-args

Tags: smartcontracts

how do i deploy a smart contract with foundry, passing an array as `--constructor-args` with `forge create`.
i have tried deploying from a script but i keep getting `Error: invalid data` even for a simple ERC20 that takes no constructor arg

Comment: forge create --rpc-url <your_rpc_url> \
    --constructor-args "ForgeUSD" "FUSD" 18 1000000000000000000000 \
    --private-key <your_private_key> src/MyToken.sol:MyToken \
    --etherscan-api-key <your_etherscan_api_key> \
    --verify                                                                                           Did you try this?

Comment: Yes I did this, and it works the way you put it, but in my case one of my args was an array of addresses.

Comment: Yes, i figured out how to pass array arguments in constructor while deploying, i made example with uints but it also works for adrresses, check answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Everything working, i put uint array in constructor, so thats why i pass numbers, just for example.

```
forge create --rpc-url "your RPC url" --constructor-args [10,20,30] 
--private-key "your private key" src/Counter.sol:Counter --etherscan-api-key 
"your api key" --verify
```

Also i had a problem with passing few arguments

```
--constructor-args [10, 20, 30]
```

this will not work, you need to pass them together, like this - [10,20,30]. Hope i was useful.